# sphinx and languages other than English

Tags: internationalization, python-sphinx

I found in

`http://svn.python.org/projects/doctools/trunk/sphinx/locale`

support for several languages that can be used in Sphinx but I did not find the instructions on how to install it: which files should be downloaded and installed in which directories?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found out already. These files are already present in my installation.  In order to use a foreign language it should be specified in file `conf.py` through the variable *language*.

-- Tsf